# How to disable the chat after certain conversation in Bot Framework v4

Tags: c#, botframework

I am creating a simple chat bot in Bot Framework v4.0.

I have this right now:

[image: Image of Bot Emulator here]

As you can see, when the user says "Sure thank you" the chat ends; however, I want to completely disable the chat textbox not allowing any text to be entered by user.

To end the conversation I am using this code:

```
return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
```

How is it possible in Bot Framework? Or is this even possible?

**Language Used:** C#,

**Bot Framework:** 4.0

Answer (score 1):

This is easily achievable by passing an event activity from your bot. This is then picked up by Web Chat. The hosting HTML page has an event listener that, when the event is picked up by Web Chat, is initiated. The event listener can then be used to alter the state of your page, including Web Chat elements.

Look over the [c.incoming-activity-event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/c.incoming-activity-event) sample for reference.

*Note: You should also be aware that, when directly altering the DOM in this way, you make your code susceptible to breaking changes in the future should Web Chat revisions come thru that alters the currently published code.*

Hope of help!

Comment: thank you sir! I will try this one. As of now, I am just upvoting it as you gave me an idea to proceed. Once it is successfully achieved I will definitely mark it as answer.